# Verifying the identity $E\left( \int^t_0 X_s ds \right)^2 = \int^t_0 \int^t_0 E(X_s X_u)\,ds\, du$

Tags: stochastic-processes, expectation, stochastic-integrals

I am doing the following exercise:

[image]

The thing I am struggling with is the identity given in the hint:
$$
E\left( \int^t_0 X_s ds \right)^2 = \int^t_0 \int^t_0 E(X_s X_u)\,ds\, du
$$
I am unable to verify this. I have tried various starting points like writing
$$
E\left( \int^t_0 X_s ds \right) =\int_{\Omega} \int^t_0 X_s \, ds \, d\mathbb P
$$, looking at Fubini's theorem etc, but I seem to be missing the correct starting point. Much appreciated if someone could show me this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the squared integral as
$$ \left( \int_0^t X_s \, ds \right)^2 = \left( \int_0^t X_s \, ds \right)\left( \int_0^t X_u \, du \right) = \int_0^t \int_0^t X_s X_u \, ds \, du, $$
where I have applied Fubini's theorem since the intervals are finite and the functions are integrable. Now use the definition of expectation:
$$ \mathbb{E}\left( \int_0^t X_s \, ds \right)^2 = \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t \int_0^t X_s X_u \, ds \, du \right] = \int_{\Omega} \left( \int_0^t \int_0^t X_s X_u \, ds \, du \right) \, d\mathbb{P} $$
Now all you have to do is to justify using Fubini again, to push the $\mathbb{E}$ integral inside.